# Is there a way to apply OneHot encoded SciPy Sparse Matrix to PCA?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, pca

I have data that has both numeric and cathegoric attributes that I'm trying to apply the PCA analysis. For the cathegoric ones I OneHot encoded them using sklearn.preprocessing OneHotEncoder, but when I apply the matrix to sklearn.decomposition PCA it gives me the following error:

*TypeError: PCA does not support sparse input. See TruncatedSVD for a possible alternative.*

I want to use the PCA because my data has also numeric atributes besides the categoric that I'm trying to OneHot encode. I could just either convert the SciPy sparse matrix to the dense NumPy array and append it to my df (I don't know if it'd provide decent results as I don't have much knowledge in statistics) but I wanted to know if there's a way to apply the sparse matrix directly to PCA in case I run into a bigger set of data.

Further information:

I'm using the "Horse Colic Dataset".

You can download it here: http://networkrepository.com/horse-colic.php

The datadict may be obtained here: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Horse+Colic

Comment: `M.toarray()` or `M.A` makes a regular numpy array from the sparse one.  But if `M` is large, that may produce a memory error.  There are `sklearn` functions that work with sparse matrices.  That should be clear in the respective docs.  If the function doesn't work with sparse there isn't any other way.